# javascript to add option element to a select list, but with custom data attributes

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to insert an additional select option to a list,  but with specific data elements:

```
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("mySelectList");
    var option = document.createElement('option', {
        "data-img-src": "https://blah",
        "data-img-alt": "https://blah"
    });
    option.text = "New Image";
    x.add(option);
}
```

This is intended to allow image-picker to detect the additional item and hopefully display it.

But the additional attributes are ignored.
I'd really appreciate some help please, as I'm going out of my mind.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I would add that `x.add` is not valid, use `appendChild` instead : [Node.appendChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild)

To sum up :

```
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("mySelectList");
  var option = document.createElement('option');
  option.text = "New Image";
  option.setAttribute("data-img-src", "https://blah");
  option.setAttribute("data-img-alt", "https://blah");
  x.appendChild(option);
}
```

Comment: Yes - quite right..   thanks.  its now working using this above code..   thanks very much for the help.    Is it JQuery thats meaning that the x.appendChild(option) works in my real code,  but the x.add(option) worked on a more basic example?

Answer (score 0):

use [setAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute) :

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("mySelectList");
  var option = document.createElement('option');
  option.text = "New Image";
  option.setAttribute("data-img-src", "https://blah");
  option.setAttribute("data-img-alt", "https://blah");
  x.add(option);
}

myFunction()
```

```html
<select id="mySelectList">

</select>
```

Comment: Thanks very much.  That's perfect.

Answer (score 0):

The second argument you are using isn't valid for [createElement()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement)

> options
>   An optional ElementCreationOptions object containing a single
>   property named is, whose value is the tag name for a custom element
>   previously defined using customElements.define(). See Web component
>   example for more details.

Use `setAttribute()` or `dataset["name"]` to set data-* attributes

```
option.setAttribute("data-img-src", "https://blah");
option.setAttribute("data-img-alt", "https://blah");

//note dataset uses camelcase for dashed names
option.dataset["imgSrc"] = "https://blah";
option.dataset["imgAlt"] = "https://blah";
```

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("mySelectList");
  var option = document.createElement('option');
  option.text = "New Image";
  option.setAttribute("data-img-src","https://blah");
  option.setAttribute("data-img-alt","https://blah");
  x.add(option);
  
  //just for displaying what the attributes were set to
  document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend',`<br>src: ${option.dataset.imgSrc}`);
}

document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click',myFunction);
```

```html
<select id="mySelectList"></select>
<button>Add</button>
```